# What needs to be put into the uriPath field when creating a StatementProperty in AWS CDK (Java)?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

We want to create a webACL for AWS WAF, using the latest version (2.51.1) of AWS CDK and Java 17 (corretto).

One of the rules we want to define contains a URI path that is to be allowed. We use the following definition:

```
Object emptyUriPath; // How to define this?
StatementProperty apiV1Order = StatementProperty.builder()
    .byteMatchStatement(ByteMatchStatementProperty.builder()
        .searchString("/the/path/to/allow")
        .positionalConstraint("STARTS_WITH")
        .fieldToMatch(FieldToMatchProperty.builder()
            .uriPath(emptyUriPath)
            .build())
        .textTransformations(List.of(TextTransformationProperty.builder()
            .priority(0)
            .type("LOWERCASE")
            .build()))
        .build())
    .build();
```

The question is: How does the `uriPath` need to be defined? The documentation is quite sparse about this.

The documentation says that the `uriPath` field shall contain an 'empty object'. In TypeScript, this seems to be quite easy. But for Java, we get various errors for the different attempts we tried:

```
Object emptyUriPath = new Object();
Object emptyUriPath = new JsonObject();
Object emptyUriPath = "{}";
```

cause errors like this:

```
An exception occured while executing the Java class. No serializer found for class java.lang.Object and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.ImmutableCollections$List12[1]) (through reference chain: software.amazon.jsii.api.CreateRequest["args"]->java.util.Arrays$ArrayList[2])
```

or this:

```
An exception occured while executing the Java class. JsonObject (through reference chain: com.google.gson.JsonObject["asBoolean"]) (through reference chain: java.util.ImmutableCollections$List12[1]) (through reference chain: software.amazon.jsii.api.CreateRequest["args"]->java.util.Arrays$ArrayList[2])
```

or this:

```
An exception occured while executing the Java class. Error: Resolution error: Supplied properties not correct for "CfnWebACLProps"
[ERROR]   rules: element 1: supplied properties not correct for "RuleProperty"
[ERROR]     statement: supplied properties not correct for "StatementProperty"
[ERROR]       byteMatchStatement: supplied properties not correct for "ByteMatchStatementProperty"
[ERROR]         fieldToMatch: supplied properties not correct for "FieldToMatchProperty"
[ERROR]           uriPath: "{}" should be an 'object'.
[ERROR] @jsii/kernel.RuntimeError: Error: Resolution error: Supplied properties not correct for "CfnWebACLProps"
[ERROR]   rules: element 1: supplied properties not correct for "RuleProperty"
[ERROR]     statement: supplied properties not correct for "StatementProperty"
[ERROR]       byteMatchStatement: supplied properties not correct for "ByteMatchStatementProperty"
[ERROR]         fieldToMatch: supplied properties not correct for "FieldToMatchProperty"
[ERROR]           uriPath: "{}" should be an 'object'.
```

We would have assumed something like this:

```
Object emptyUriPath = UriPathProperty.builder().build();
```

but such a property doesn't exist (only something similar for the [SDK](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/wafv2/model/UriPath.html)).

Can anyone please tell us what to do? Can also be a hint on how to create such a rule/statement in a completely different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the CDK developers we found out that `emptyUriPath` needs to look like this:

```
Map<String, String> emptyUriPath = Map.of("UriPath", "{}");
```

see also the [documentation about generic structures here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/work-with-cdk-java.html#java-cdk-idioms).

For those who may have the same problem:
It turned out that we had another issue in our rule property definition: an action definition was missing. The final rule property definition now looks like this:

```
RuleProperty.builder()
        .name("AllowValidApiCalls")
        .priority(1)
        .statement(apiV1Order)
        .action(RuleActionProperty.builder()
            .allow(AllowActionProperty.builder()
                .build())
            .build())
        .visibilityConfig(VisibilityConfigProperty.builder()
            .cloudWatchMetricsEnabled(false)
            .metricName("metricName")
            .sampledRequestsEnabled(false)
            .build())
        .build();
```